# Getting a format error, cannot convert system.double to system.string

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, pie-chart

Question1#
While executing the below code its giving me a format error. System.double cannot be convert into System.string.

```
var PiePriorityCount = dt.AsEnumerable()
                       .GroupBy(item => item.Field<string>("Priority"))
                       .Select(item => new { Priority = item.Key, TicketCount = item.Count() });


        dtPriorityCount.Columns.Add("Priority", typeof(string));
        dtPriorityCount.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(int));
        lblStatus.Visible = true;
        foreach (var itm in PiePriorityCount)
        {
            //lblStatus.Text = "Z" + "->" + itm.TicketCount;
            DataRow dr = dtPriorityCount.NewRow();
            dr["Priority"] = "P" + " " +itm.Priority; 
            dr["Count"] = itm.TicketCount;
            dtPriorityCount.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

While executing the above code its giving me a format error. System.double cannot be convert into System.string.

**Question 2# Got the Answer**
In the Sting, LOG, contains Status on the first line and Owned Group on the second line and Assigned Group on the third. So i want the sub-string to be After status till the end of the line. i.e. Assigned (1)

And they can be shuffled in order. Not necessary that the first one will be status, it can be owned group or assigned group.

```
string LOG = "Status: Assigned (1) \n Owned Group: Jitesh - poiuyt \n Assigned Group: Jitesh - QWERTY";

string tb = "Status: ";
string tb1 = "Assigned Group: ";

int lenght = tb.Length;
int a = LOG.IndexOf(tb) + lenght;

int lenght1 = tb1.Length;
int a1 = LOG.IndexOf(tb1) + lenght1;

var status = LOG.Substring(a,'\n');
var status1 = LOG.Substring(a1, '\n');
```

Expected Output :
 
status = Assigned (1)
status1 = Jitesh - QWERTY

Current Output :
status = Assigned (
status1 = Jitesh - Q

This is what i am expecting and this is what i am getting.

Comment: Consider picking a more meaningful topic.

Comment: This is just confusing. Cant get the last sentence. Please show off how the output should look like without any comments within. One cant differenciate between your comments and parts that should belong to the output.

Comment: You can use `Split`: 1) with `\n`, and then 2) with `:`. `LOG.Split('\n').Select(n => n.Split(':').LastOrDefault().Trim()).ToList()`. You will have 2 values there, the first is `status`, the second one is `status1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Split` twice:

- with `\n` to get `Status: Assigned (1)`  and  `Assigned Group: Jitesh - QWERTY`, and then
- with `:` and trim the values.

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/Y7zA5v):

```
var LOG = "Status: Assigned (1) \n Owned Group: Jitesh - poiuyt \n Assigned Group: Jitesh - QWERTY";
var res = LOG.Split('\n')
    .Where(p => p.Trim().StartsWith("Status:") || p.Trim().StartsWith("Assigned Group:"))
    .Select(n => n.Split(':').LastOrDefault().Trim())
    .ToList();

var status = res[0];
var status1 = res[1];
```

You will have 2 values there, the first is `status`, the second one is `status1`.

**Another way** to get 2 variables if their order can be random:

```
var status = LOG.Split('\n')
    .Where(p => p.Trim().StartsWith("Status:"))
    .Select(n => n.Split(':').LastOrDefault().Trim())
    .FirstOrDefault();
var status1 = LOG.Split('\n')
    .Where(p => p.Trim().StartsWith("Assigned Group:"))
    .Select(n => n.Split(':').LastOrDefault().Trim())
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/WYGuWA)

Comment: Thanks Man, its giving the output now but what was the problem with my way of trying. It was only giving first 10 characters.

Comment: There is a small change in question. Please look into it.

Comment: I see the task is getting more complicated. Do you need to get the substrings after `Status:` and `Assigned Group:`? I updated the answer to account for those 2 in any position.

Comment: Should there be always both values? Or can there be one missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
string LOG = "Status: Assigned (1) \n Assigned Group: Jitesh - QWERTY";

var split =  LOG.Split('\n');
var status = split[0].Split(':')[1];
var status1 = split[1].Split(':')[1];
```

Comment: Not giving the desired output :(